# Muscle gain if we sleep 7 hours instead of 9 hours

Tags: muscle-gain, sleep

Mr.A & Mr.B, Mr.C all three workout in same level & eat same amount of protein & Carbs....

Mr.A sleeps for **9 hours**....

Mr.B sleeps for **8 hours**....

Mr.C sleeps for **7 hour**s....

**Is Mr. A build the muscle early [ or more ] than Mr.C ?**

How much **sleep** really matters for **muscle gain**?....

In our Gym , some seniors tell they sleep only 6 hours due to lack of time, still they have good muscles!....

Comment: This is going to be fairly individual, I'm not sure that you will get a concrete answer.

Comment: @JohnP Why would it be individual?

Comment: @endolith - Because each person has different metabolisms, habits, growth potential, genetics, and so forth. What may work for me may or may not work for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. A. This is assuming all 3 participants have the same experience, nutrients, genetics/potential, program etc. Sleep is one of the most important things next to nutrition when it comes to building your body. Also prevents alzheimer's and improves immunity.

> If you’re dieting, but not getting sufficient sleep, 70% of all the weight you lose will come from lean muscle, not fat – our body becomes resistant at giving up fat when it’s underslept"

-Sleep Expert and Neuroscientist Dr. Matthew Walker

Highly recommend his book Why We Sleep: Unlocking the Power of Sleep and Dreams.

Answer (score 4):

I'm writing an article on sleep at the moment and I found the study you reference here. Not only was there no control group (to test what the effects would be against making no changes), but the study was only done with 10 people - this is a shockingly small sample size.

Furthermore, one of the main findings they quote - that the sleep deprived group lost 55% less fat than the other group - had a P value of 0.043. This means that there was a 43% chance it was a random coincidence. That's way too high to draw any solid conclusions.

I agree, sleep is incredibly important and there is virtually no literature that suggests sleep deprivation improves muscle growth/recovery, however using this individual study to claim sleep=muscle growth probably isn't the most reliable.

Link to the study here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20921542/

Matthew Walker's book is littered with scientific illiteracy like this. Check out this for fact busting: https://guzey.com/books/why-we-sleep/#the-potential-harm-done-by-the-book

Comment: Wouldn't a p value of .043 correspond to a ***4.3%*** chance, not a 43% chance?